# Cannot create folders/subfolders in Windows 10 Mail

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1703, windows-mail

I was attempting to follow the directions from this [MS article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-do-I-add-or-remove-folders-in-Mail-for-Windows-10-e30d69e1-16fd-45d1-b339-8a2a4db73ffe).  However, there is no `+` button and right-clicking reveals no option to create a new folder.

[image]

I have followed all the troubleshooting steps in the article, including closing and reopening Mail (and rebooting) as well as checking for updates (none available).

**How can I create new folders in Windows Mail?**

Comment: Do you use the IMAP protocol?

Comment: Ahhhh, nope! This particular account is POP3 which doesn't support folders.  Hadn't even thought about it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The POP3 mail protocol does not support any type of folder structure.  This happened to be a POP3 account.  That is the reason the folder functionality was not available.

I have submitted feedback on the office.com article suggesting they include information about POP3 limitations.